# Using images to style scroll bars?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Can anyone recommend the best solution for using images to style scroll bar?  I guess a decent cross-browser solution would involve a merge of JQuery/javascrip and CSS?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using the [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) jQuery plugin for this. It lets you use CSS to style scroll bars. If you want to use images, you'd use the `background-image` property, as the [Lozenge theme demo](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/themes/lozenge/) shows.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://almaer.com/blog/creating-custom-scrollbars-with-css-how-css-isnt-great-for-every-task) article will get you going.

BTW: There is no such thing as best :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:
http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

Many very good solutions. Always remember to think as you're users would do. In my oppinion animated / designed scrollbars can ruin the beauty about scrolling, because of delay or lag.